# Persistent os-level environment variables in ubuntu-latest GitHub runner

Tags: ubuntu, python, environment-variables, github

> **What specific syntax must be changed below in order to set an OS-level environment variable that can be consumed by a python app through `os.environ` in an ubuntu-latest GitHub runner from a GitHub workflow?**

**USE CASE:**

The use case is that a python 3.10 app called `my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py` running in the ubuntu-latest GitHub runner needs to consume the value of `MY_VAR_ONE` from the python object `os.environ`.

**THE PROBLEM:**

The problem is that we are getting permission denied errors whenever the workflow below tries to write to `/etc/environment`, or to `/etc/bashrc`, or to `/etc/profile`.

**THINGS WE TRIED:**

We tried setting GitHub workflow environment variables, but GitHub environment variables do not propagate into Python's `os.environ`.  We tested this by printing out the contents of `os.environ` from within the Python 3.10 app, but none of the GitHub-defined environment variables were present in `os.environ` .

Also, the `export MY_VAR_ONE=/path/to/some.yaml` command below fails to create a persistent os-level environment variable that remains when the `my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py` app is running.

**GITHUB WORKFLOW:**

Here is the GitHub workflow which includes the ubuntu-latest startup script which must set persistent environment variables and then trigger `my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py` :

```
name: set-os-environ-var
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  set-os-environ-var:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: bash
        name: Configure agent
        run: |
          export MY_VAR_ONE=/path/to/some.yaml
          sudo echo "export MY_VAR_ONE=/path/to/some.yaml" >> /etc/environment
          sudo echo "export MY_VAR_ONE=/path/to/some.yaml" >> /etc/bashrc
          sudo echo "export MY_VAR_ONE=/path/to/some.yaml" >> /etc/profile
          python my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py
```

**APP THAT CONSUMES ENVIRON VARIABLES:**

Here is a stripped down example of `my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py`:

```
import os
#The output from this next line must include MY_VAR_ONE , but does not currently.  
print("os.environ contains: ", str(os.environ))
```

Comment: `steps:` looks like it takes `env:` values? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps

Comment: @thrig The approach you suggest fails to get the variables into `os.environ` and thus leaves the variables invisible within the python app.  The approach you suggest only works within the bash startup script itself, and not within apps called by the startup script that need to access os-level environment variables.  The code to reproduce this given in the OP is so simple that it would only take you a moment to recreate this problem if you have a GitHub account and if you are willing to noodle with this.

Comment: Please update this question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That means something we can copy, paste, and run to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `env` keyword in your workflow is exactly the correct answer. If we write:

```
name: set-os-environ-var
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  set-os-environ-var:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      MY_VAR_ONE: /path/to/some.yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: bash
        name: Configure agent
        run: |
          python my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py
```

Then the `MY_VAR_ONE` environment variable will be available to all
steps in the `set-os-environ-var` job, and `my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py` will see that value in `os.environ`.

Comment: You can see this workflow in action [here](https://github.com/larsks/sandbox/runs/8052044347?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:7). I *think* any signed in user should be able to see the build logs.

Comment: Adding your syntax to our more complex object-oriented python app results in your print command printing out as `MY_VAR_ONE: <unset>` .  I also printed out the entire `os.environ` contents and manually reviewed every every variable to see that `MY_VAR_ONE` is not in `os.environ` when the object-oriented app calls `os.environ`.  I have not run your stripped down example yet.  But I can confirm that your syntax does not transfer into a more complex object-oriented app called in the same way from the same script in the same ubuntu-latest runner.  Why do you think the problem is persisting?

Comment: If you can post code that reproduces the problem I'd like to see it. If you look at [my example](https://github.com/larsks/sandbox/blob/main/my-app-that-consumes-os-level-environ-variables.py), the only way it works is if the value of `MY_VAR_ONE` is in fact set in the environment. I suspect a problem with your code, but if you don't post it we can only guess.